# Tiktok api /user/info endpoint

Tags: python, python-requests, tiktok

Edit: Since this question is getting a good amount of views, I'd like to let you all know before you waste hours of your life on the upload endpoint that it currently requires you to manually click `confirm` in the app. So it doesn't allow you to fully automate uploads. To anyone which this saves time, you're welcome :)

Currently trying to implement the TikTok api into one of my projects. However having a few difficulties with a specific endpoint. Not sure if its an error on my part or on Tiktoks.

Upon making the below request I am recieving an `invalid request body` error message. I have followed their documentation to the T so unsure why this is happening?

https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/login-kit-user-info-basic

```
    data = {
        "access_token": access_token,
        "open_id": open_id,
        "fields": [
            "open_id",
            "union_id",
            "avatar_url",
            "avatar_url_100",
            "avatar_url_200",
            "avatar_large_url",
            "display_name"
        ]
    }

    user_info = requests.post("https://open-api.tiktok.com/user/info/", data=data)

    print(user_info.json())
```

```
{'data': {}, 'error': {'code': 6007055, 'log_id': '', 'message': 'invalid request body'}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `json` parameter instead of `data`

```
import requests
data = {
        "access_token": access_token,
        "open_id": open_id,
        "fields": [
            "open_id",
            "union_id",
            "avatar_url",
            "avatar_url_100",
            "avatar_url_200",
            "avatar_large_url",
            "display_name"
        ]
    }

user_info = requests.post("https://open-api.tiktok.com/user/info/", json=data)

print(user_info.json())
```